# Fill BETWEEN with result of SELECT-Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

#### Where I am

I would like to filter a table based on another Table. Both are rather big, so efficiency is key here. The following statement runs very slowly, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id1 in (SELECT id2 FROM table2
              WHERE scenario = 123)
```

#### Improvement

Since IDs (here id1, id2) are assigned sequentially, I can do fill a BETWEEN statement like this, but it runs the second query twice.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id1 BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(id2) FROM table2
                   WHERE scenario = 123)
          AND     (SELECT MAX(id2) FROM table2
                   WHERE scenario = 123)
```

#### Goal

I would prefer something like this (kind of pseudo code):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id1 BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(id2), MAX(id2) FROM table2
                   WHERE scenario = 123)
```

#### Final Thoughts

I am aware of the fact that this is more prone to errors in contrast to the initial solution. I also tried to filter by joining both tables yet this is also too slow. Any other, even more efficient solutions are also much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t2.id2 = t1.id1 AND t2.scenario = 123
             );
```

And then you want an index on `table2(id2, scenario)`.

This basically scans `table1` and for each row, looks up (quickly) the matching row in `table2` to see if it exists.

Comment: Looks good, could you elaborate how the EXISTS is working here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: would there be a way to use BETWEEN in some way like I intended?

Comment: @mnist . . . There is no need to use `BETWEEN`.  Looking for the exact match is going to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

For your first query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE id1 in (SELECT id2 FROM table2
              WHERE scenario = 123);
```

The following index on the `table2` table should help:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON table2 (scenario, id2);
```

You may also try the following variant:

```
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON table2 (id2, scenario);
```

As to which index would work the best, it depends on the cardinality of the `scenario` field.  If that field were very restrictive, then it would be best to use the first version of the index, would let SQL Server immediately discard many records from `table2` before even attempting the lookup of `id2`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated!